# How do I select clients with no valid email addresses?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Client table that is linked to a Client Contact table. Naturally there may be multiple contacts for many clients.
I have a Select statement using DISTINCT to show me which Clients have at least one email contact in the Client Contact table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT intpkautoclientid
FROM   tblclient c
       JOIN tblclientcontact cc WITH (nolock)
         ON cc.intfkclientid = c.intpkautoclientid
WHERE  NULLIF(cc.stremail, '') IS NOT NULL
ORDER  BY intpkautoclientid
```

Is there a simple way using the above select to return all clients not part of the ‘Clients with email addresses’ SET.

I really want to know which clients I do not have any valid email addresses for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tblclient
WHERE   intpkautoclientid NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  intfkclientid
        FROM    tblclientcontact
        WHERE   stremail > ''
        )
```

Comment: Quite simple when you know how. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Another readable way is using [`NOT EXISTS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx):

```
SELECT intpkautoclientid
FROM   tblclient c
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM tblclientcontact cc 
   WHERE cc.intfkclientid = c.intpkautoclientid
)
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you. A variation on @Quassnoi answer

Answer (score 0):

Change your join to a `left outer join` and the `where` clause to test for Nullness:

```
SELECT DISTINCT intpkautoclientid
FROM   tblclient c
       left outer JOIN tblclientcontact cc WITH (nolock)
         ON cc.intfkclientid = c.intpkautoclientid and cc.stremail is not null
WHERE  cc.stremail is null
ORDER  BY intpkautoclientid
```

Also, the `distinct` is probably no longer necessary.

Comment: I don't think this will work as if a Client has two contacts one with an valid email and one that is empty. It will return the Client. I am wanting Clients that I have no email information for. ???

Comment: @kingchris . . . I was thinking about that when I wrote it, but the question said nothing about this situation.  In any case, that is easily fixed with the addition of `cc.stremail is not null1` in the `on` clause.